# Why do I get an incorrect graph when I plot a function with multiplication expressed by parentheses?

Tags: pgfplots

When plotting certain expressions with pgfplots it seems to give the wrong result. Consider the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.7,
  no marks
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot{(x)(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

in which I take `(x)(x)` to express y=x^2. If that is the case it should produce an U-shaped curve but it does not.

[image: The result of the code, not an U-shaped curve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that pgfplots does not recognize any multiplication in `(x)(x)`. You have to express multiplication explicitly, e.g. as `x * x`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.7,
  no marks
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot{x * x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: The result of the code, an U-shaped curve]

`\addplot` uses the math parser of PGF and in [the manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) it says that

> Parenthesis can be used to change the order of the evaluation.

But it does *not* say anything about parentheses being able to invoke the multiply function (which `*` does).